# Automatic login on subdomain Amazon Cognito Identity

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I use Amazon Cognito Identity SDK for JavaScript to log in my users at www.mydomain.com.

I was wondering if it was possible to have my users automatically logged in on store.mydomain.com

For what i know Cognito stores the logintoken and other things in localstorage and that can't be reached from subdomains?

Answer (score 2):

AWS Cognito JS SDK uses LocalStorage to store the authentication tokens by default. You can change this behavior and use cookies to store the tokens. Then you can use your parent domain name while setting the cookies and all your sub-domains can access this cookie.

To achieve this, you can use the [CookieStorage class](https://github.com/amazon-archives/amazon-cognito-identity-js/blob/master/src/CookieStorage.js) from the JS SDK while creating the [CognitoUserPool](https://github.com/amazon-archives/amazon-cognito-identity-js/blob/master/src/CognitoUserPool.js) objects.

**TypeScript Code snippets below**

Full implementation can be found [here](https://github.com/sarthakj178/aws-cognito-authn/blob/master/src/app/services/authentication.service.ts). A running application can be viewed [here](http://sarthakj178.com/aws-cognito-authn/).

To authenticate the User (on the main domain, say, example.com) -

```
signIn(email: string, password: string): Observable<any> {
    let userPool = new CognitoUserPool({
       UserPoolId: environment._USER_POOL_ID,
       ClientId: environment._CLIENT_ID,
       Storage: new CookieStorage({secure: false, domain: "example.com"}),
    });
    let authenticationDetails = new AuthenticationDetails({
      Username: email,
      Password: password,
    });

    let userData = {
        Username: email,
        Pool: userPool,
        Storage: new CookieStorage({secure: false, domain: "example.com"}),
    };
    let cognitoUser = new CognitoUser(userData);
    return Observable.create((observer: Observer<any>) => {
      cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
        onSuccess: result => {
          observer.next(result);
          observer.complete();
        },
        onFailure: error => observer.error(error),
      });
    });
}
```

To check if user is authenticated (on a subdomain, say, sub.example.com)

```
isAuthenticated(): Observable<boolean> {
    let userPool = new CognitoUserPool({
       UserPoolId: environment._USER_POOL_ID,
       ClientId: environment._CLIENT_ID,
       Storage: new CookieStorage({secure: false, domain: "example.com"}),
    });
    let cognitoUser = userPool.getCurrentUser();
    if (cognitoUser != null) {
      return Observable.create((observer: Observer<boolean>) => {
        cognitoUser.getSession((error, session) => {
          if (error) {
            console.error(error);
            observer.next(false);
            observer.complete();
          }
          console.log(session, session.isValid(), session.isAuthenticated);
          observer.next(session.isValid());
          observer.complete();
        });
      })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The tokens for the Amazon Cognito Identity SDK for JavaScript are stored in local storage indeed. However, if you use the Cognito Hosted UI and the Cognito Auth SDK linked below, you can manage SSO.

The way that works, if you have tokens stored against the local storage of your domain, you can login. Otherwise, you hit our login endpoint and if there is a cookie stored against it, you get tokens in the response that will be stored in local storage and can be accessed with the Amazon Cognito Identity SDK (cause they are stored in the same location).

https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-auth-js